# Git: Making a PR consisting of current branch's changes that depends on changes of another branch

Tags: git, github, branch

Title might sounds a bit confusing but I would like to know how to make the PR that only shows changes of branch 2 that depends on changes of branch 1.

For example, let's say I have a branch called `generate-rails-app`. This branch is strictly for generating a new rails app. I generate the app and make a PR.

On the other hand, I would like to have another branch called `add-styling-to-table-in-rails-app` that depends on the generated rails app.

However, I would need to wait for someone to approve and merge the PR for `generate-rails-app` before I can work on `add-styling-to-table-in-rails-app`, and this would put me on hold as I can't go further. So when I am in `generate-rails-app`, I will create a new branch `add-styling-to-table-in-rails-app` and add some styling.

Then I will make a PR for `add-styling-to-table-in-rails-app`, but the issue is that changes from `generate-rails-app` is shown in the PR of `add-styling-to-table-in-rails-app`. I don't want this. I want the second PR to only show the styling changes that I made, not the fact that I generated the app as that has already been done on the first PR.

What are the steps to take?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't. The way github works is that it shows *all* changes your branch would bring into the target branch, once merged. That some of these branches are also on another branch, and will (hopefully) be merged into the target branch before your changes, is not taken into account. Also, if you end up creating a PR before the previous branch/PR has been merged, and your PR is resolved first, it would be *your* PR that introduces those changes into the target branch.

Comment: However, once the first branch/PR has been merged into the target branch, your PR should hopefully stop showing these changes, so this might be a temporary thing. I would have to check though if github shows PR changes as "compared to the target branch" or "since you created your branch".

Comment: Perhaps your target branch should be the branch related to the first PR? Since if you've already started working on modifications to something that hasn't been merged, is it really done?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you!